# How to know which piece of code runs on driver or executor?

Tags: apache-spark

I am new to Spark. How to know which piece of code will run on the driver & which will run on the executors ?

Do we always have to try to code such that everything runs on the executors ?. Is there any recommendations/ways to make most of your code to run on executors ?

Update: I far as I understand Transformations run on executors & actions runs on driver because it needs to return value. So is it fine if the action runs on driver or should it also run on executor ? Where does the driver actually run ? on cluster ?

Comment: Good question but is bit broad can you give some example observations you found to answer in specific.. Spark or any other distributed framework designed to address big data requirements executed in distributed way.

Comment: In spark foreach and take, both are actions but foreach runs on driver node where as take runs on executor nodes. Can anyone explain why?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Any Spark application consists of a single Driver process and one or more Executor processes. The Driver process will run on the Master node of your cluster and the Executor processes run on the Worker nodes. You can increase or decrease the number of Executor processes dynamically depending upon your usage but the Driver process will exist throughout the lifetime of your application.

The Driver process is responsible for a lot of things including directing the overall control flow of your application, restarting failed stages and the entire high level direction of how your application will process the data.

Coding your application so that more data is processed by Executors falls more under the purview of optimising your application so that it processes data more efficiently/faster making use of all the resources available to it in the cluster.
In practice, you do not really need to worry about making sure that more of your data is being processed by executors.

That being said, there are some Actions, which when triggered, necessarily involve shuffling around of data. If you call the `collect` action on an RDD, all the data is brought to the Driver process and if your RDD had a sufficiently large amount of data in it, an `Out Of Memory` error will be triggered by the application, as the single machine running the Driver process will not be able to hold all the data.

Keeping the above in mind, Transformations are lazy and Actions are not.
Transformations basically transform one RDD into another. But calling a transformation on an RDD does not actually result in any data being processed anywhere, Driver or Executor. All a transformation does is that it adds to the DAG's lineage graph which will be executed when an Action is called.

So the actual processing happens when you call an Action on an RDD. The simplest example is that of calling `collect`. As soon as an action is called, Spark gets to work and executes the previously saved DAG computations on the specified RDD, returning the result back. Where these computations are executed depends entirely on your application.

Comment: Where does I/O happen?  If you are doing reads to HDFS or S3, does that happen from the driver or from the executors?

Comment: Reading from HDFS, the driver will create an RDD with the number of partitions of the RDD corresponding to the number of HDFS blocks the file is stored in. The partitions will be spread out over the executors. When the data needs to be processed, the executors will read their specific partitions to perform the computations.

Comment: Thanks.  Does this also apply to S3?

Comment: Related to previous comments: code to manage HDFS files, like moving or deleting single files or directories, runs in the driver, right?

Comment: I have another Related Question, When I ```show``` or ```take``` a RDD in spark. all of my data will send to driver? or just the results? what you said about ```collect``` is correct about all the actions?

Answer (score 28):

There is no simple and straightforward answer here.

As a rule of thumb everything that is executed inside closures of higher order functions like `mapPartitions` (`map`, `filter`, `flatMap`) or `combineByKey` should be handled mostly by executor machines. Everything outside these are handled by the driver. But you have to be aware that it is a serious simplification.

Depending on a specific method and language at least a part of the job can be handled by the driver. For example when you use `combine`-like methods (`reduce`, `aggregate`) final merging is applied locally on the driver machine. Complex algorithms (like many can ML / MLlib tools) can interleave distributed and local processing when needed.

Moreover data processing is only a fraction of a whole job. Driver is responsible for bookeeping, accumulator processing, initial broadcasting and other secondary tasks. It also handles lineage and DAG processing and generating execution plans for higher level APIs (`Dataset`, `SparkSQL`).

While the whole picture is relatively complex in practice your choices are relatively limited. You can:

- Avoid collecting data (`collect`, `toLocalIterator`) to process locally.
- Perform more work on the workers with `tree*` (`treeAggregate`, `treeReduce`) methods.
- Avoid unnecessary tasks which increase bookkeeping costs.

Comment: +1 But since septra's answer is in simple language & easy to understand for new spark user, so accepting that.

Comment: +1 for treeAggregate and treeReduce methods
https://umbertogriffo.gitbooks.io/apache-spark-best-practices-and-tuning/content/treereduce_and_treeaggregate_demystified.html

Answer (score 0):

To this part of your question "**Update: I far as I understand Transformations run on executors & actions runs on the driver because it needs to return value**. "

It is not true that only transformation runs on the executor and all actions run on the driver.

If we have to join 2 datasets where there is no aggregate operation that needs to be performed eg :

```
dataset1.join(dataset2,dataset1.col("colA").equalTo(dataset2.col("colA)),
                "left_semi").as(Encoders.bean(Some.class)).write("/user/datasetresult");
```

In this case, as soon as the executor machine completes working on its partition it starts writing down the result to HDFS/some persistence without waiting for other executors to complete. This is the reason why we see different part files, which are technically partitions that each executor processed.
Driver does not wait for all executors to complete its computation.

**Where does the driver actually run? on cluster?**

Depends on the --deploy-mode chosen.
If --deploy-mode client then the gateway where you launch your spark application is your driver machine.
If --deploy-mode cluster, cluster manager choose a machine(in yarn/mesos) which it feels has sufficient memory to run as the driver.